# Creating relationships between nodes of the same label?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database of architectural style periods, imported from a csv. Each `Style` has a `styId`, and an `infId` which shows the previous styles that have influenced it.

I would like to create relationships between the styles if they are mentioned as an influence, like so:

##### Anglo-saxon style influenced by Roman style

[image: Anglo-saxon style influenced by Roman style]

##### styId and infId with matching values

[image: styId and infId with matching values]

I know that this will be a case of matching the `styId` to the `infId` but I am not a data scientist and very new to NEO4j. I can do this by manually specifying relationships, but I'm building this dataset myself and plan to add more entries later, so if there is a best practice to creating these relationships by going off of the `styId` and `infId` alone I'd much prefer that option.

Thanks for any help, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Why are only some of the "Influences" values reflected as `infId` values; are there missing Style rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the data in your DB, you can use a query like the following. It also removes the redundant `infId` property after creating the relationships.

```
MATCH (s1:Style)
WITH s1, SPLIT(s1.infId, ';') AS infs
MATCH (s2:Style)
WHERE s2.styId IN infs
CREATE (s1)-[:INFLUENCED_BY]->(s2)
REMOVE s1.infId // Remove redundant infId property
```

Beforehand, you should create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) on the `styId` property of `Style`, to speed up the query:

```
CREATE INDEX Style_styId FOR (s:Style) ON (s.styId)
```

##### Alternate suggestion

But, even better, you should have created the data model you wanted when ingesting the data into your DB, instead of fixing up the DB afterwards.

There are multiple [ways to import CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/data-import/csv-import/) into neo4j. The simplest is via [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/), so here is an example. Assuming your CSV file has a header row:

```
CALL {
  LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///styles.csv' AS r
  CREATE (s:Style {id: r.styId, name: r.Style, dates: r.Dates, influences: SPLIT(r.Influences, ';')})
  MERGE (loc:Location {name: r.Location})
  CREATE (s)-[:LOCATION]->(l)
}
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///styles.csv' AS row
MATCH (s1:Style)
WHERE s1.id = row.styId
WITH s1, SPLIT(s1.infId, ';') AS infs
MATCH (s2:Style)
WHERE s2.id IN infs
CREATE (s1)-[:INFLUENCED_BY]->(s2)
```

You may also want to create an index on `Location.name` if you have more than a few locations.

Note that this creates a slightly different data model than yours, in that:

- each `Style` node points to a unique `Location` node
- the `influences` property (which you may want to omit) is a list of strings
- the `styId` is stored as the `id` property (since it is obvious that the id is for a style). This requires that your id index is created like this:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX Style_id FOR (s:Style) ON (s.id)
  ```

The ingestion is done with 2 imports from the CSV file; the first is for creating all the `Style` nodes, and the second is for creating all the `INFLUENCED_BY` relationships. The [CALL subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/subqueries/call-subquery/) is used to cleanly separate the 2 `LOAD CSV` invocations (otherwise, you would need to perform an aggregation between them just to reduce the number of rows back down to 1).

The above solution assumes you do not have a lot of styles, and so it does everything in a single transaction. If you have a lot of styles, you will have to change (and perhaps split up) the query to avoid running out of memory and/or taking too long.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I am trying to use CREATE INDEX line in your example but I'm getting Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'INDEX'. Read that it requires priviledges in the link you posted - do I have to grant the priviledges to myself to create an index? I'm using the desktop version, and I am the only user of the database.

Comment: I think Desktop by default gives the `neo4j` user full access. I have never had an issue creating indexes using `neo4j`. Are you using the `neo4j` user? Also, what version of neo4j are you using? The `CREATE INDEX` syntax has changed over time.

Comment: I've updated to the current version and still having this issue - will post another question for it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Remember, your relationships can have properties and they too can be indexed. A major advantage of graphs is the relationships, unlike a RBDS database, are not mere connections. They have knowledge. This can be used for provenance, filtered traversals, storing unique data that should not be in the connected nodes, etc.

If you want examples, look at how this was done with DNA segments that are used in matching persons in genealogy. With a well developed knowledge graph you create amazing vale ... such as re-creating your ancestor's DNA

https://www.wai.md/post/the-field-of-dreams-ancestor-avatars